# In Qt4, converting from XSLT to HTML, key function is not available

Tags: html, c++, xml, xslt, qt4

In Qt4, when converting from a XML file to a HTML file by using XSLT tranformation like this:

```
QXmlQuery query(QXmlQuery::XSLT20);
QString output;
query.setFocus(QUrl(_final_output_filepath.c_str()));
query.setQuery(xslt_code.c_str());
query.evaluateTo(&output);
```

I get the following error:

```
Error XPST0017 in file:///tmp/test, at line 1, column 1: No function with name fn:key is available.
```

When trying to execute the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('gprofq',$ts_name)">
   <pre><xsl:value-of select="."/></pre>
</xsl:for-each>
```

key was previously defined out of the template as follows:

```
<xsl:key name="gprofq" match="gprofitem" use="@bin"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't come across QT4 before, but it seems to be primarily an XQuery engine. The documentation here

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/xmlprocessing.html#xslt-2-0

says that XSLT support is experimental, and keys are not yet implemented.